# Can't get a proper link using Laravel and Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Well I got this problem for a few days now. My issue is:
In my .vue page I created the followed link to download a simple PDF file:

```
<a href= {{ asset('download/form.pdf') }}> Download here. </a>
```

(The link shows up normally.)

The blade:

```
@extends('layouts.esic')   
@section('content')
<solicitante></solicitante>
@endsection
```

But when I click DOWNLOAD HERE I got a error back:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

I mean. The file is placed at the public folder and code seems okay. Am I missing something?

Cheers!

Comment: The code snippet you are showing doesn't really help us know what is going on. Have you tried any debugging?

Comment: You can see for yourself: http://www.iacu.ba.indap.com.br/esic/presencial after you click on "Download do Formulário" an error occurs.

Comment: Is it possible just create a link to the exactly path? something like <a href="yoursite.com.br/file.pdf?

Comment: Use the asset function. Is your form.off in the /public/download directory?

Comment: that's right.  /public/download

Comment: So did my comment solve your question?

Comment: Not sure, just getting a error now: Warning: require(/home/indap986/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/indap986/public_html/index.php on line 22

Comment: It appears that your auto load file isn't being found. Did you mess with it based on someone else's suggestion? Try running composer dump-autoload.

Comment: composer dumpautoload worked fine! But I don't get, When I change something and pull to the server it crashes again.

Comment: Is your server updating it's composer packages as well?

Comment: I don't think it does, why?

Comment: How I do that? Sorry, I'm a neewbie.

Comment: Usually, you have a .gitignore file in your project which lists your vendor directory, which means that your server does not get passed any of your vendor files. You must run composer update on your server and then re-update and re-migrate every time you push to the server. Laravel Forge really makes this a snap, or you can make your own deploying script.

Answer (score 1):

To make itaccessible from the web, you need to create a symbolic link from public/storage/downlaod to storage/app/public/download

> ln -s /home/vagrant/Code/laravel-project-name/storage/app/public/download /home/vagrant/Code/laravel-project-name/public/storage/download

Comment: gonna try this, I'll let you know if it worked! Thanks

Comment: I found the path in the file filesystems.php and it says:  'root' => storage_path('app/public') 'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage'. So, where should I put my PDF file? /storage or /public?

Comment: under storage/app/public

Comment: Can't I just create a link to the exactly path? something like <a href="yoursite.com.br/public_html/file.pdf?

Comment: If you want direct path than put your files under public directory, which can be accessible from any user.

Answer (score 1):

if your download folder is located at public folder you can props to import your specific file.

laravel Blade

```
 @extends('layouts.esic')   
    @section('content')
    <solicitante :pdf ="{{ json_encode(asset('download/form.pdf')) }}"></solicitante>
    @endsection
```

component vue. (something like this one)

```
<template>
<a href= {{ pdf }}> Download here. </a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 props: ['pdf'],

 ..............
```

Im not sure if this way are you looking for, 
(sharing some idea :)

Comment: what about the storage folder? I see laravel as a powerful framework, but sometimes it's a pain in the ass...

Comment: I update my answer. I dont know if that way are you looking for.

Comment: You need to make a symlink between storage folder and the public folder as stated in here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

Comment: about this part:
<script>
export default {
 props: ['pdf'],
 ..............
It already has:
 export default {
        props: ['resource'],
        data() {
--Can I put two exports in the same <script> or should I open a new one?

Comment: Can't I just create a link to the exactly path? something like <a href="yoursite.com.br/public_html/file.pdf?

Comment: you can create a new props like this one "props: ['pdf','pdf2']" and then in your laravel blade like this " <solicitante :pdf ="{{ json_encode(asset('download/form.pdf')) }}" :pdf2="{{ json_encode(asset('download/form.pdf')) }}"></solicitante> " . I wish it can help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this one if you want to just insert a link in vue

```
<a v-bind:href="url">{{ url }}</a>

export default {
  data() {
    return  { url: 'http://anywhere.com'  };
  }
}
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Can I just create a link to the exactly path? something like <a href="http://yoursite.com.br/public_html/file.pdf?

Comment: Where should I insert this? Sorry I'm a beginner:

Comment: You can insert this in your vue file directly,